# How to Compress bulk insert with elastic4s and HttpClient

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, apache-httpclient-4.x, elastic4s

I try to compress the bulk insert into ElasticSearch but I have some trouble.

I have no idea how to do it.

There is the code :

```
 val client = HttpClient(ElasticsearchClientUri("localhost", 9200))

 client.execute {
    bulk(
      indexInto("myindex" / "mytype").fields("country" -> "Mongolia", "capital" -> "Ulaanbaatar"),
      indexInto("myindex" / "mytype").fields("country" -> "Namibia", "capital" -> "Windhoek")
    )
 }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: How did you try to compress it exactly?

Comment: About the compression :
Elastic search support Compression if you set the compression in headers `Content-Encoding`
So you need to compresse the body int Gzip for example and add the headers  `Content-Encoding:gzip`

Comment: Right but I was wondering how you tried to do it in elastic4s. The answer is you didn't, but you're asking how you _could_ do it.

Comment: yes you can do it with elastic 4s you need:
- in elastic4s client add the header 
- overide execute methode and compress the bulk